# MySQL, Rails ActiveRecord date grouping and timezones

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone

I want to count users by creation date.
When I query my last user, I have:

```
 > User.last.created_at
 => Thu, 07 Aug 2014 21:37:55 BRT -03:00
```

When I count users per date I get this:

```
> User.group("date(created_at)").count
=>  {Fri, 08 Aug 2014=>1}
```

The creation date is Aug 7, but the result is Aug 8. This is happening because the group condition is in UTC and my timezone is 'Brasilia'.
I have this in my `application.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I just found this gem: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate Perhaps that might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try convert_tz first:

```
User.group("date(convert_tz(created_at,'UTC','[your_time_zone]'))").count
```

If the convert_tz returns null, maybe you will need to load the timezone tables with this command line:

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

Referrence to [mysql convert_tz](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Edit 1:

If you use Rackspace MySQL, you will need to enable root access to the database and run the timezone queries as root. [Here you can find](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/access-slow-query-and-general-logs-for-cloud-databases) instructions to how install `trove` and enable root access using rackspace API.

Comment: This would be a perfect answer, but my MySQL running in Rackspace does not have the timezones tables loaded. Is there any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Without time zone function, just add hours.

```
User.group("date(created_at + INTERVAL 8 HOUR)").count
```

Add 8 hours is Shanghai's time zone. Welcome to Shanghai.

Comment: It is a good hack, but I will have to also consider summer time saving periods to get the correct time.

Comment: You can set Time.zone to the current string for your timezone and then do Time.zone.now.utc_offset / 3600 to figure out the exact interval to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your database always saves in UTC (unless you modify it) even though your app is configured to use Brasilia Local Time. When you use a 'where' statement, Rails gives you the option to say the time zone you are. But the group statement there is no such thing. One solution is to use a database specific function (like @JaugarChang answer ). Another is doing this:

```
group = User.group("date(created_at)").count
results = group.map{|date, count| {Time.zone.utc_to_local(DateTime.parse(date)).to_date => count } }
```

- Pro: You don't depend on specific database native functions to
  convert time zone;
- Con: Not so fast compared to the first one.
  Requires more Timezone knowledge for a programmer to understand
  what's going on here.